# How to add multiple email address to a SNS topic via cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

is it possible to add more than one email address to a SNS topic subscription via cloudformation

```
SNSTopic:
   Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
   Properties:
    Subscription:
    - protocol:email
      Endpoint: abc@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **no loops** in CFN. So you have to explicitly list all your email addresses:

```
SNSTopic:
   Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
   Properties:
    Subscription:
    - protocol:email
      Endpoint: abc@gmail.com
    - protocol:email
      Endpoint: second@gmail.com
    - protocol:email
      Endpoint: third@gmail.com
```

If you want to do it dynamically, you have to create your own [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).